# Issue in verifying SAML response "enveloped signature"

Tags: python, xml, cryptography, saml, digital-signature

Can anybody advise if the below could be a correct format for the `SignedInfo` element to be passed to some code to digitally sign the  xml message?

```xml
<ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
  <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod>
  <ds:Reference URI="#pfxffef2099-cc79-fd84-e7e8-5bdced364715">
    <ds:Transforms>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"></ds:Transform>      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
    <ds:DigestValue>LC/2Thrnfl3SUqWp8LXfZFyXoZA=</ds:DigestValue>
  </ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
```

And should the below python code do the job?

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import utils
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
    with open("mysaml_pr_key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            key_file.read(),
            password=None,
            backend=default_backend()
        )
    mypadding_for_signature=padding.PSS(
    mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA1()),
    salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH
    )
    hasher2 = hashes.Hash(hashes.SHA1())
    hasher2.update(to_be_signed.encode())
    digest_of_signed_info=hasher2.finalize()
    signature_before_64encode=private_key.sign(digest_of_signed_info,mypadding_for_signature,utils.prehashed(hashes.SHA1()))
    signature=base64.b64encode(signature_before_64encode)
```

The response is rejected by the SP and the reason is "failing to verify the signature".

As per the documentation of the SP, I did upload the IDP certificate and the CA which signed it and they should be used in signature verification. Further, I did try to validate the signature in third party tools and the same response is returned (signature verification failed.) ..

I expect that one of the below two reasons caused the failure:

1. The syntax or the canonicalization of the XML element `<SignedInfo>` is wrong. As per my understanding the signature is the production of signing of the SHA1 digest of the `<SignedInfo>` element. Note that the `<DigestValue>` is the hash of the XML node whose ID is given int the `<reference>` element. I did verfiy that my hash is the same as the hash produced by a third party tool (online SAML tool)
2. Maybe the python code I use to sign the element is wrong. I need to use SHA1 then sign using my private key

Comment: The `SignedInfo` portion probably shouldn't have any `<CR><LF>` characters in it when calculating... The canonicalization method shown removes extra whitespace, including `<CR><LF>`. I would suggest using a SAML package, rather than trying to build your own - there are a lot of rules around processing and handling of signing and encryption. I would also note that SHA-1 is no longer generally accepted in the enterprise for signing.

Comment: Hello there, tried to remove white spaces and line feeds. But I am again suspecting my code.(please review above)..Regarding SHA1 I am using it just for testing purpose... And I would appreciate if you recommended a library that I can use instead of building code from scratch.

Comment: Signatures are definitely one of the hardest bits to get right in SAML. It requires an understanding of how PKI works, an understanding of math, random numbers, etc. You're way better off using something like the `python3-saml` (for Python3) or `python-saml` (for Python2) packages than trying to build your own SP handler. Both are readily available in pypi.

Answer (score 0):

RSA algorithms used in the [W3C XML Signature Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/) refers to the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 algorithm described in [RFC 3447](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.html#section-8.2.1). The used padding method is PKCS#1 v1.5. Your python code uses PSS padding

Comment: you are correct regarding padding type. I changed the code to the below. But still signature verification is failing. '    hasher2 = hashes.Hash(hashes.SHA1())
    hasher2.update(to_be_signed.encode())
    digest_of_signed_info=hasher2.finalize()
    import hashlib
    # digest_of_signed_info = hashlib.sha1(to_be_signed.encode()).hexdigest()
    # digest_of_signed_info=digest_of_signed_info.encode()
    #digest_of_signed_info=base64.b64encode(digest_of_signed_info)
    signature_before_64encode=private_key.sign(digest_of_signed_info,padding.PKCS1v15(),utils.Prehashed(hashes.SHA1()))'

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked:

the final signedinfo element is:

```
<ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
  <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod>
  <ds:Reference URI="#pfxffef2099-cc79-fd84-e7e8-5bdced364715">
    <ds:Transforms>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
    <ds:DigestValue>YeKgITtMiXZjSnfQ1I+byM6aOoQ=</ds:DigestValue>
  </ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
```

I think the issue was mentioning the wrong CanonicalizationMethod.

The code for singing is:

```
with open("mysaml_pr_key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key_file.read(),
        password=None,
        backend=default_backend()
    )

signature_before_64encode = private_key.sign(to_be_signed,padding.PKCS1v15(),hashes.SHA1())
signature=base64.b64encode(signature_before_64encode)
```

where to_be_signed is the the .encode() result of singedinfo string.